# Substring comparison across columns within Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a large dataset pasted into Google Sheets.  I want to compare two columns in this sheet. 
 The first column is filled with long strings, I only care about the first character in each cell in this column.

The second column is text-based.  I want to paste data into a new sheet *if* the string in column A starts a number (not a letter) *and* the text in column B is "Early".

My challenge is using Javascript to get only the substring of 1 character for column A.  The error is "TypeError: str.substring is not a function."  I have also tried slice() as well to no effect.  Is this not supported in Apps Script?

How can I isolate those first characters and then compare alongside the other column?

I also then need to push the rows that meet this criteria in *both* columns to a new tab.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('data');
  var str = sheet.getRange('A:A').getValues(); 
  var char = str.substring(0,2);
  var stage = sheet.getRange('B:B');
  var endColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var value_stage = (stage.getValues());
  var value_char = (char.getValues());

  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('new_sheet'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];
    for (i=0; i<value_char.length;i++) {
      if 
      (
        (
          ( value_char[i] == '0') ||
          ( value_char[i] == '1') ||
          ( value_char[i] == '2') ||
          ( value_char[i] == '3') || etc... )

       &&
          ( value_stage[i] == 'Early')
)

  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,endColumn).getValues());
  j.push(i);
 }
 }
 csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

SAMPLE DATA BELOW:

```
**ID**                                **Stage**  **Name**
A               texthere                Early   Bob
B               abcdefgh                Late    Sally
52              texthere                Early   Jim
C               thesdfas                Late    Allan
00              tsdfsdfd                Late    Susan
11              qqwerrww                Early   Ryan
Q               tsdfsagd                Early   Sarah
98              fdsafads                Early   Evan
09              fdasfdsa                Early   Paul
10              abcdefgh                New     Megan
10              abcdefgh                Early   Cooper





NOTE:  in the real dataset, columns A and B are actually K & L
```

And the ID column has those spaces between the early part of the string and the end.  This is what I am trying to slice off

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh=ss.getSheetByName('data');
var svs=sh.getRange(1,2,sheet.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
var csh=ss.getSheetByName('new_sheet');
var data=[];
var j=[];
svs.forEach(function(r,i){
  if((r[0].slice(0,1)=='1' || r[0].slice(0,1)=='2') && r[1]=='Early') {
  //do what you want in here
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey Cooper, thank you for your reply.  However, I am a bit confused still.  I don't see where your code is able to split the string in each cell of column A?  The goal is to essentially overwrite the values in every cell in column A with _only_ the first character in that cell.   I have tried using splice(), split(), substr(), substring(), etc...

Comment: If that doesn't work share some data as a csv.   You can post it into a code area and then we can copy and paste it into spreadsheet.

Comment: What I need to do, is get a substring of _only_ the first 2 characters in each cell in column A.  If those 2 characters are both numerical _and_ B is "Early," then do actions.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Lh_L9kmb6i4QkIfVvQ7T8HNXlR1w1rQMhgThNYU4Mk/edit

Comment: It's basically just =LEFT(x,2) that I'm looking for, but the ability to SELECT cells with certain criteria from that, without overwriting them

Comment: That is actually what you are describing. If you need both (first and second) characters just go ahead and change the `r[0].slice(0,1)` to `r[0].slice(0,2)` then use a RegExp to check they are both numbers, something like `r[0].slice(0,2).match(/^\d*$/)` or [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test). But take into account that @Cooper actually resolved the *challenge* you proposed because you only said 1st character.

Comment: Ah you're right - @Cooper and @ Raserhin.  I apologize for the confusion, changed the parameters partway through.  Looking to get 2 digits.  Regardless...I am getting hung up setting the array then calling each element of it to be sliced individually as a string, rather than slicing pieces of the array.  It seems to be storing my data as boolean, my log is printing [true] [true] [true] etc.

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh=ss.getSheetByName('data');
var svs=sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
var data=[];
var j=[];
Logger.log(svs) 
`

Comment: Also, Slice() still failing as a function.  ERROR:  r[0].slice is not a function

Comment: I'll take a look. Can you share a few lines of sample data?

Comment: sample data [link] https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Lh_L9kmb6i4QkIfVvQ7T8HNXlR1w1rQMhgThNYU4Mk/edit [link]

Comment: Sorry but I refuse to follow links to spreadsheet.  Please post a small amount of sample data to your question the same as you would code.   Preferably csv so it can be copied and pasted directily into spreadsheet.

Comment: Comma separated.  The spaces in column A are part of the data.  Note that in the actual dataset, ID and Stage are not columns A and B.  They are K and L. 
 I just put them here as it's easier to work with `ID,Stage,Name
A               texthere,Early,Bob
B               abcdefgh,Late,Sally
52              textherelots of text with spaces,Early,Jim
C               the cells in question have both text and numbers,Late,Allan
00              there is always the same amoutn of spaces after the initial text,Late,Susan
11              ACBD739,Early,Ryan
10               314234 ,Early,Cooper`

Comment: @Cooper let me know if the above data works for you!

Comment: It looks like slice() is cutting items from the array, not characters from each string within the array.  How can I do the latter?  `var string_arrach = sheet.getRange('A:A');
var values = string_arrach.getValues();
var data = [];
var sliced = values.slice(0,values.length-18); Logger.log(sliced); `

Comment: Data is not usable to me.  Try posting it in the question the same way you did the code.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper, I added sample data.  Three columns and 11 rows, plus a header

Comment: I think I figured it out! `for(i in input) {
    k = input[i][0].toString().substr(0,1);
    l = input[i][1];  if(!isNaN(k) && etc `